# Capitalize every other letter within exploded array

Tags: php, uppercase, lowercase

Initially i had posted a question to find a solution to capitalize every other letter in a string. Thankfully Alex @ SOF was able to offer a great solution, however ive been unable to get it to work with an array... To be clear what im trying to do in this case is explode quotes, capitalize every other letter in the array then implode them back.

```
if (stripos($data, 'test') !== false) {
$arr = explode('"', $data);

$newStr = '';
foreach($arr as $index => $char) {
$newStr .= ($index % 2) ? strtolower($char) : strtoupper($char);
}

$data = implode('"', $arr);
}
```

Comment: Do you mean you only want the alternate caps inside of `"` delimited portions of your string, e.g. output should be `hello "HoW ArE YoU DoInG?"`.

Comment: I hAvE a BiT oF fEaR oF wHaT aRe YoU dOiNg WiTh ThIs EvErY oThEr LeTtEr CaPiTaLiZeD tExT

Comment: @Ariel I'm messing around with creating a cipher as a fun project with my son, seemingly unreadable without a php key which will perform conversion, replaces, etc...

Comment: I wrote an answer that does that :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the anonymous function requires >= PHP 5.3. If not, just make the callback a normal function. You could use `create_function()`, but it is rather ugly.

```
$str = '"hello" how you "doing?"';

$str = preg_replace_callback('/"(.+?)"/', function($matches) {
  $newStr = '';
   foreach(str_split($matches[0]) as $index => $char) {
       $newStr .= ($index % 2) ? strtolower($char) : strtoupper($char);
   }
   return $newStr;

}, $str);

var_dump($str);
```

#### Output

```
string(24) ""hElLo" how you "dOiNg?""
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.viper-7.com/ivojyx).

If you want to swap the case, swap the `strtolower()` and `strtoupper()` calls.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
 foreach($data as $key => $val)
    {
       if($key%2==0) $data[$key] = strtoupper($data[$key]);
       else $data[$key] = strtolower($data[$key]);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Or.... instead of using regular expression you could just not even use the explode method, and go with every other character and capitalize it.  Here is an example:

```
$test = "test code here";

        $count = strlen($test);
        echo "Count = " . $count . '<br/>';
        for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++)
        {
            if($i % 2 == 0)
            {
                $test[$i] = strtolower($test[$i]);
            }
            else 
            {
                $test[$i] = strtoupper($test[$i]);
            }
        }
        echo "Test = " . $test;
```

The secret lies in the modulus operator. ;)

Edit:  Dang, I just noticed the post above me by Jordan Arsenault already submitted this answer... I got stuck on the regex answer I missed that :-/ sorry Jordan, you were already on point.